# Changing the look of MOSS 2007 DropDown navigation menu

Tags: sharepoint, moss

How can I completely change the look of the TopNavigation dropdowns in SharePoint 2007?

Basically I need to change the look of the div popup that gets display.  I need to use Javascript to do this, so just changing the CSS for the menus won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Grab a copy of the [MossMenu](http://blogs.msdn.com/ecm/archive/2006/12/02/customizing-the-wss-3-0-moss-2007-menu-control-mossmenu-source-code-released.aspx) code the MS team released, implement and override the render with your own code. Peasy

Answer (score 0):

Telerik has a few pages that show you how to use their controls instead of the the dropdown menu in MOSS. The directions start here http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/moss-overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at Heather Solomon's Blog for [MOSS 2007 CSS reference](http://www.heathersolomon.com/content/sp07cssreference.htm). You will most likely get want you want out of that.